# Task Database Schema and select Query Based on Slot

Tags: mysql

I have created a database schema to manage task. There are 2 types of task.

1. Slot wise task (For ex. 10 AM to 12 PM, 12 PM to 3 PM etc). (These are recurring task which will appear daily for a user to whom it is assigned).
2. Task with deadline. (These are one time task given).
   For slot wise task, only 1 entry will be created in task table, completed status will be fetched using task_status table.
   Tables are mentioned below

```
#task_slot
CREATE TABLE `task_slot` (
    `task_slot_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `slot` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`task_slot_id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

#Users table
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `first_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    `last_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    `active` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '0-inactive; 1-active',
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

#task table
CREATE TABLE `task` (
    `task_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `task_given_by` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `task_slot_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `task_title` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `task_detail` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `task_status` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL COMMENT '0 - pending, 1 - completed',
    `created` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `completed_on` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `task_type` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL COMMENT '1 - slot wise, 2 - deadline wise',
    `deadline` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `task_given_to` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`task_id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `task_given_by_rltn` (`task_given_by`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `task_given_to_rltn` (`task_given_to`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `task_given_by_rltn` FOREIGN KEY (`task_given_by`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `task_given_to_rltn` FOREIGN KEY (`task_given_to`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;


#task_status (This table will store completed status of slot wise task)
CREATE TABLE `task_status` (
    `task_status_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `task_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `task_completed_on` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`task_status_id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `task_id_status_rltn` (`task_id`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `task_id_status_rltn` FOREIGN KEY (`task_id`) REFERENCES `task` (`task_id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;


#Insert data as below
INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`,`active`) VALUES (80, 'aaaa', 'vvvv',1);
INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`,`active`) VALUES (83, 'bbbb', 'dddd', 1);

INSERT INTO `task_slot` (`task_slot_id`, `slot`) VALUES (5, '10 AM to 12 PM');
INSERT INTO `task_slot` (`task_slot_id`, `slot`) VALUES (6, '12 PM to 3 PM');
INSERT INTO `task_slot` (`task_slot_id`, `slot`) VALUES (7, '3 PM to 7 PM');
INSERT INTO `task_slot` (`task_slot_id`, `slot`) VALUES (8, '7 PM to 9 PM');

INSERT INTO `task` (`task_id`, `task_given_by`, `task_slot_id`, `task_title`, `task_detail`, `task_status`, `created`, `completed_on`, `task_type`, `deadline`, `task_given_to`) VALUES (6, 80, NULL, 'task title 1', 'task title 1 description task title 1 description task title 1 description', 1, '2023-08-08 20:45:36', '2023-08-19 16:29:41', 2, '2020-12-01', 83);
INSERT INTO `task` (`task_id`, `task_given_by`, `task_slot_id`, `task_title`, `task_detail`, `task_status`, `created`, `completed_on`, `task_type`, `deadline`, `task_given_to`) VALUES (7, 80, 1, 'task title 2', 'task title 2 description', 0, '2023-08-13 01:50:09', NULL, 1, NULL, 83);
INSERT INTO `task` (`task_id`, `task_given_by`, `task_slot_id`, `task_title`, `task_detail`, `task_status`, `created`, `completed_on`, `task_type`, `deadline`, `task_given_to`) VALUES (8, 80, NULL, 'Tttt', 'Vvvg', 1, '2023-08-17 22:21:38', '2023-08-19 16:23:55', 2, '2023-08-24', 83);
INSERT INTO `task` (`task_id`, `task_given_by`, `task_slot_id`, `task_title`, `task_detail`, `task_status`, `created`, `completed_on`, `task_type`, `deadline`, `task_given_to`) VALUES (13, 80, 3, 'task title 3', 'task title 33  description', 0, '2023-08-13 01:50:09', NULL, 1, NULL, 83);


INSERT INTO `task_status` (`task_status_id`, `task_id`, `task_completed_on`) VALUES (7, 7, '2023-08-17 16:36:57');
INSERT INTO `task_status` (`task_status_id`, `task_id`, `task_completed_on`) VALUES (8, 13, '2023-08-17 16:38:33');
INSERT INTO `task_status` (`task_status_id`, `task_id`, `task_completed_on`) VALUES (9, 13, '2023-08-19 16:40:41');
```

Is this can be optimized? If yes, then how? If no, I am not able to write the select query properly.

I tried creating select query. I am able to get the result.
Left join is giving repetitive result. For example, if 1 slot task is completed yesterday and today, then this query is giving result as completed and not completed both.

```
SELECT t.`task_id`,ts.slot, t.`task_given_by`, t.`task_slot_id`, t.`task_title`, t.`task_detail`, 
IF(DATE_FORMAT(tst.task_completed_on, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2023-08-19', 1, 0) AS `task_status`, 
t.`created`, IF(DATE_FORMAT(tst.task_completed_on, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2023-08-19', tst.task_completed_on, NULL) AS `task_completed_on`, t.`task_type`, t.`deadline`, t.`task_given_to`,
            concat(u1.first_name, ' ', u1.last_name) AS task_given_by_name, CONCAT(u2.first_name, ' ', u2.last_name) AS task_given_to_name
            FROM `task` t LEFT JOIN task_slot ts ON ts.task_slot_id = t.task_slot_id
            left join users u1 ON u1.user_id = t.task_given_by 
            LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u2.user_id = t.task_given_to
            LEFT JOIN task_status tst ON tst.task_id = t.task_id
            WHERE `task_given_to` = 83 and task_type = 1
```

I want to fetch each task as a single row which are not yet completed for today (In case of slot wise task).

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question

Comment: there are still information missing see https://dbfiddle.uk/M7r9_UXK

Comment: Sorry I have missed to add users table insert queries. I have added.  Please try now.

Comment: the time slots are not processable without parsing the text, that is bad also time and date should be in in one column that would make the calculation if the time slot is already passed much easier

Comment: That would make more sense only if I need to calculate time slot is already passed but that is not my requirement. Would you be able to check the select query mentioned in the end? I am trying to fetch slot task assigned to user. These are actually fixed recurring task which user have to complete daily, in select query, I want task which are due today + task which are completed today (without repetitive data). Left join is giving repetitive data.